# Invertible matrix polynomial without constant

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that if a polynomial Q without constant term such that
 $$ ||I-Q(A)|| <1 $$
then, A is invertible

Comment: Show that $Q(A)=I-(I-Q(A))$ has an inverse $I+(I-Q(A))+(I-Q(A))^2+(I-Q(A))^3+...$. Finally, $Q(A)=A\cdot P(A)$ for some polynomial $P$. Therefore $A$ must be invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on $\vert \vert \cdot \vert\vert$, it's not true in general. If ur using $\vert\vert A \vert \vert= Max_{x\in sphere} \vert \vert Ax \vert \vert$ :

If $x\in ker(A)\cap sphere$, you get $ \vert\vert I-Q(A)\vert \vert \geq  \vert \vert Ix-Q(A)x \vert \vert=\vert \vert x \vert \vert=1$ ($Q(A)x=0$ because $Q$ has no constant term); contradiction

Comment: Its mean that it is not necessary..

Comment: @Yaar  what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean to say the statement I wrote is not true for all norms?

Comment: @Yaar no it is not true for all norms. You need "at least" a norm of algebras. Your working over the real field ?  complex ?

Comment: I am just studing convergence of iteration methods numerical analysis